# PHP serialize override private|protected and stdClass "reflection"

Tags: php, serialization

I read in Marco Pivetta article that class `private` and `protected` properties can be read through   simple casting via  `(array)` with appending before properties some `"keys"`:

`"\0*\0"` - for protected;
`"\0CLASSNAME\0"` - for private.

```
class Foo {
  protected $a  = 'protected_prop';
  private $b = 'private_prop';

  function out(){
     var_dump($this->a);
     var_dump($this->b);
  }
}

$F = new F();
$data = (array)$F;
var_dump($data["\0*\0a"]);
var_dump($data["\0Foo\0b"]);
// output
string(14) "protected_prop" 
string(12) "private_prop"
```

Then I decided to try override private and protected properties. This "key" (\0Foo\0b) recalled me about serilization.

```
$F = serialize($F);
$F = str_replace('protected_prop','new_protected_prop',$F);
$F = str_replace('private_prop','new_private_prop',$F);
$F = preg_replace_callback ( '!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!', function($match) {      
   return ($match[1] == strlen($match[2])) ? $match[0] : 's:' . strlen($match[2]) .   ':"' . $match[2] . '";';
 },$F ); //  fix unserialize(): Error at offset after str_replacing. Found on SO ^)

$F = unserialize($F);
if ($F instanceof Foo){
   $F->out();
}   
// output
string(18) "new_protected_prop" 
string(16) "new_private_prop" 
object(Foo)#1 (2) { 
 ["a":protected]=> string(18) "new_protected_prop"  // changed
 ["b":"Foo":private]=> string(16) "new_private_prop" // changed
}
```

Question: why we can outside change all private and protected properties through this method? Or it language(PHP) collision in serialization? Thanks.

http://3v4l.org/nKLFs

Comment: How do you think what is meaning of "protected"?

Comment: @sectus what is means in OOP - outside access (reading/writing) to private and protected members.

Comment: Languange do not have to protect private and protected members from all possible modification, IMHO. And even more those members could be edited by languange by design (Reflection). Also editing text of serialization object is not part of OOP concept.